# Слово file в python

Tags: python

Есть мнение, что использование слова `file` в качестве имени аргумента функции - это быдлокодерство. Так ли это? Это ведь не зарезервированное слово языка *Python*, так в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А где такое мнение существует?

Comment: В некоторых кругах моего общения.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Проблема в том, что использование переменных с теми же именами что и у `__buitins__` не позволяет в той же области видимости вызывать эти самые `__buitins__`. Например, часто переопределяют `type`, `id`, и если далее по коду необходимо воспользоваться встроенными одноимёнными функциями, то возникают проблемы. Ну и естественно эта проблема распространяется на аргументы функций, которые также распространяются на всю область видимости функции.

Моё мнение - пересечение области видимости с `__builtins__` допустимо, но по возможности стараться избегать. Есть случаи, когда просто избежать не получается - например, когда определяешь схему базы данных и у тебя есть колонка с названием `id`. Не выкрутишься. В `Django` вместо `id` предпочтительнее использовать `pk`, например, который по умолчанию ссылается на `id`.

Comment: `file` нет в `__builtins__`.

Comment: @Avernial В питоне 2.7 `file` есть в `__builtins__`, и использовать сие как переменную крайне нежелательно

Comment: Да, действительно. Уже по умолчанию считаю, что все относится к 3 питону.

Comment: @andreymal: не могли бы вы привести явные доводы, почему `file` (именно `file` имя) *"крайне нежелательно"* использовать. Где вы видели что `file` используется как `__builtin__.file`? Как часто такое использование обосновано?

Comment: @jfs https://i.imgur.com/9VndrsG.png

Comment: @jfs и вообще в вашем ответе написан ответ на ваш же вопрос :)

Comment: @andreymal: картинка просто показывает что `file is __builtin__.file` -- у вас были сомнения в этом факте или вы думали, что я это как-то пропустил? Ещё раз: где вы видели, что `file` используется как `__builtin__.file`? (рабочий код, в котором используется  непереопределённое имя `file`) Вы сказали *"крайне нежелательно"* --  я хочу услышать *явные* аргументы почему. Мои аргументы приведены в моём ответе -- я хочу услышать ваши (может я не прав -- я часто ошибаюсь, но способен менять позицию, если доводы убедительны). Можно ваши доводы в виде ответа на данный вопрос привести.

Comment: @jfs потому что `file` есть в `__builtins__`. Вот и всё. Используется оно где-то или нет — неважно.

Comment: @jfs впрочем, и используется тоже: `"isinstance(fp, file)"` (в кавычках) весьма неплохо гуглится. И, кстати, среди прочего выдаёт одну из старых версий numpy ;) В последней версии с гитхаба использования `file`, правда, не нашёл (наверняка связано с портированием на третий питон), но всё-таки.

Comment: @andreymal: *"Используется оно где-то или нет — неважно."* -- ["A Foolish Consistency is the Hobgoblin of Little Minds"](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/258/23044). `isinstance(fp, file)` -- это обоснованное применение встроенного `file` на Питоне 2, но это *крайне* редкая конструкция, поэтому можно явно `__builtin__.file` написать в этом редчайшем случае.  Резюме: утверждение "крайне нежелательно" не обосновано (сила аргументов не соответствует *категоричности* утверждения).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44297/discussion-between-andreymal-and-jfs).

Answer (score 6):

В общем случае не следует использовать имена, которые конфликтуют со встроенными ([`dir(__builtins__)`](https://docs.python.org/library/builtins.html#module-builtins)) это может ввести в заблуждение при чтении кода, но `file` это *специальный случай*: `file` не является встроенным именем в Питоне 3, а на Питоне 2 [следует использовать `open()` вместо `file()` в подавляющем большинстве случаев](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11942631/4279).

Answer (score 5):

Если посмотреть документацию для `open` в `python 3`, то мы увидим что первый аргумент назван как `file`. Конечно существует вероятность того, что среди разработчиков `python` есть "быдлокодеры", но я думаю, что никаких препятствий к использованию слова file в аргументе нет.

> Help on built-in function open in module io:
>
> open(...)
>
> open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None,
>            errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None) -> file object

Comment: А в питоне 2.7 этот аргумент называется name ;)